# How to get data into my tooltip from a map?

Tags: reactjs, react-tooltip

I am using react tooltip, but I'm not sure how to get the data in my tooltip.

I would like the topline and bottomline consts to go in the tooltip.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
export const SmallCalendar = ({ events }) => {
  const mapToRender = events?.map((e) => {
    const topLine = (
      <strong>
        {e.Title} - {e.start.slice(0, -9)}
      </strong>
    );
    const bottomLine = (
      <Fragment>
        <strong>Applies to</strong>: {e.AppliesTo.join(", ")}
      </Fragment>
    );
    return (
        <div
          className={styles.eventContainer}
          data-for="registerTip"
          data-tip={e}
        >
          <div>
            <div className={styles.eventContainerDate}>
              <Moment format="MMM" className={styles.month}>
                {e.start}
              </Moment>
              <Moment format="DD" className={styles.eventContainerLarge}>
                {e.start}
              </Moment>
            </div>
            }
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {mapToRender}
      <ReactTooltip id="registerTip" place="top" effect="solid">
        <p>Yo</p>
      </ReactTooltip>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You can topline and bottomline consts pass to `data-tip` and add `data-html={true}`

Comment: <div className={styles.eventContainer} data-for="registerTip" data-html={true} data-tip={topLine}>

like so?

Comment: This tooltip displays at object object, when I do that ^ @VitaliyRayets

Comment: Yup, you pass `object`, but `data-tip` wait string

Comment: change your `topLine` const like this ```const topLine = ( `<strong>${e.Title} - ${e.start.slice(0, -9)}</strong>`);```

Comment: Can you post this as an answer, so I can confirm. Its working thank you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `topline` and `bottomline` consts pass to `data-tip` and add `data-html={true}`.
Also change your consts like this:

```
const topLine = `<strong>${e.Title} - ${e.start.slice(0, -9)}</strong>`;

const bottomLine = `<Fragment><strong>Applies to</strong>: ${e.AppliesTo.join(", ")}</Fragment>`
```